# pyqt5 I want to know how to select the row value in qtableview

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I have two tables. I want to get the selected value in `table1` and put it in `table2`.

For example, if you select 1, `table2`
I want the whole value of row 1 to be entered and the next row 5 to be added to the row 5.
In conclusion, I would like to make `table1` show the selected row value in `table2`.

I do not know exactly how to load the selected table1 value, but I think it would be better to append one value to `QStandardItemModel` in `def table1_DoubleClicked (self):` using `self.serch.table.setModel` in table2. How can I do it?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(500, 500)
        self.Table1()
        self.Table2()
        self.Layout()

    def Table1(self):
        self.select_guorpbox = QGroupBox()
        self.select_guorpbox.setTitle("Article 1")
        self.columncount = 10
        self.rowcount = 10

        self.select_table_model = QStandardItemModel(self.rowcount,self.columncount)

        for i in range(self.rowcount):
            for j in range(self.columncount):
                table = QStandardItem('test [{},{}]'.format(i,j))
                self.select_table_model.setItem(i,j,table)
                table.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.TextFilter = QSortFilterProxyModel()
        self.TextFilter.setSourceModel(self.select_table_model)
        self.TextFilter.setFilterKeyColumn(2)

        self.SerchLineEdit = QLineEdit()
        self.SerchLineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.TextFilter.setFilterRegExp)

        self.select_table = QTableView()
        self.select_table.setModel(self.TextFilter)
        self.select_table.setColumnWidth(1, 150)
        self.select_table.setColumnWidth(2, 300)
        self.select_table.setEditTriggers(QTableView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.select_table.setSelectionBehavior(QTableView.SelectRows)
        self.select_table.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.select_table.doubleClicked.connect(self.table1_DoubleClicked)
        self.select_table.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.table1_CustomContextMenu)

        # column auto sort
        # self.select_table.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)
        # self.select_table.resizeColumnsToContents()

        v = QVBoxLayout()
        v.addWidget(self.select_table)
        self.select_guorpbox.setLayout(v)

    def Table2(self):
        self.serch_groupbox = QGroupBox()
        self.serch_groupbox.setTitle("Article 2")
        lable = QLabel("~")
        lable.setFixedWidth(10)
        lable.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        insertbutton = QPushButton("insert")
        self.startdate = QDateEdit()
        self.startdate.setDate(QDate.currentDate())
        self.startdate.setFixedWidth(150)
        self.startdate.setCalendarPopup(True)
        self.enddate = QDateEdit()
        self.enddate.setDate(QDate.currentDate())
        self.enddate.setFixedWidth(150)
        self.enddate.setCalendarPopup(True)
        self.article_serch_button = QPushButton("ARTICL SERTCH")
        self.article_serch_button.setFixedWidth(250)

        self.serch_table = QTableView()

        h1 = QHBoxLayout()
        h1.addWidget(insertbutton)
        h1.addWidget(self.startdate)
        h1.addWidget(lable)
        h1.addWidget(self.enddate)
        h1.addWidget(self.article_serch_button)
        h2 = QHBoxLayout()
        h2.addWidget(self.serch_table)

        v = QVBoxLayout()
        v.addLayout(h1)
        v.addLayout(h2)

        self.serch_groupbox.setLayout(v)

    def table1_DoubleClicked(self):
        self.k =QItemSelectionModel().Select

    def table1_CustomContextMenu(self, position):
        menu = QMenu()
        menu.addAction("Add")
        menu.exec_(self.select_table.mapToGlobal(position))
        print("?")

    def Layout(self):
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.SerchLineEdit)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.select_guorpbox)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.serch_groupbox)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    fream = MainWindow()
    fream.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Do you want to copy an entire row from table 1 to table 2 when you double click on the first table? you could also better explain what you mean by: *the next row 5 to be added to the row 5*, in the case of *if you select 1, table2 I want the whole value of row 1 to be entered* one identifies the row because it was pressed but row 5 where it comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following, it copies the selected row from one table to the other:

```
def table1_DoubleClicked(self, index):
    rows = []
    row = []

    for column_index in range(self.columncount):
        cell_idx = self.select_table.model().index(index.row(), column_index)
        row.append(self.select_table.model().data(cell_idx))

    rows.append(row)

    search_table_model = QStandardItemModel(len(rows), self.columncount)

    for i in range(len(rows)):
        for j in range(self.columncount):
            search_table_model.setItem(i, j, QStandardItem(rows[i][j]))

    self.serch_table.setModel(search_table_model)
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. `self.select_table.model ()` The index method is not generated `intellisense`. Another question I have made is that when using `self.select_table.selectedIndexes ()`, I get 10 values ​​when printing to my `print()` statement. What is this?

Comment: Hi, because it counts all selected cells of the row.